# switch statement - string vs int

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line of javascript in an event handler:

```
var value =  event.currentTarget.value; //example: 9
```

which I then use in a switch statement.

```
switch (value) {

    case 9:
        return 12;
    case 12:
        return 9;
}
```

The problem is that "value" is a string instead of an int.

Should I just cast this to an int?

Or is there a way to get the value as an int, like say with jQuery()?

Or should I just use strings in the switch statement?

Comment: Good point:  `9 === "9";`  //false

Comment: Form values always return strings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Or is there a way to get the value as an int, like say with jQuery()?

Of course, this is almost always a feature provided in a language or environment. In JavaScript, there are four ways:

1. `parseInt` will parse the string as a whole number. `value = parseInt(value, 10)` will parse it as decimal (e.g., base 10, the number system most of us use). Note that `parseInt` will parse the number it finds at the beginning of the string, ignoring anything after it. So `parseInt("1blah", 10)` is `1`.
2. `parseFloat` will parse the string as a potentially-fractional number (like `1.2`), if the string contains a decimal point. It always works in base 10.
3. The `Number` function: `value = Number(value)`. That expects the *entire* string to be a number, and figures out what number base it is by looking at the string: The default is decimal, but if it starts with `0x` it's parsed as hexadecimal (base 16), and on some engines in loose mode if it starts with `0` it's parsed as octal (base 8). There's no way to force it to use a particular number base.
4. Force the engine to implicitly convert it by applying a math operator to it; the usual one is `+`. So: `value = +value`. That does the same thing `value = Number(value)` does. Oddly, it tends to be slower than `Number` on some engines, but not enough to matter.

Examples:

```
parseInt("15", 10):  15
parseFloat("15"):    15
Number("15"):        15
+"15":               15

parseInt("1.4", 10): 1
parseFloat("1.4"):   1.4
Number("1.4"):       1.4
+"1.4":              1.4

parseInt("10 nifty things", 10): 10
parseFloat("10 nifty things"):   10
Number("10 nifty things"):       NaN
+"10 nifty things":              NaN
```

Live Copy:

```js
console.log(parseInt("15", 10));              // 15
console.log(parseFloat("15"));                // 15
console.log(Number("15"));                    // 15
console.log(+"15");                           // 15

console.log(parseInt("1.4", 10));             // 1
console.log(parseFloat("1.4"));               // 1.4
console.log(Number("1.4"));                   // 1.4
console.log(+"1.4");                          // 1.4

console.log(parseInt("10 nifty things", 10)); // 10
console.log(parseFloat("10 nifty things"));   // 10
console.log(Number("10 nifty things"));       // NaN
console.log(+"10 nifty things");              // NaN
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: `value = 0 | value` could be faster if not by Number then at-least by `+`. am I wrong?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: I doubt it would be faster (not that it's likely to matter). It would also only work for whole numbers, because the bitwise operator takes the number through an integer conversion. *Edit*: I got curious, and found the Number vs. + test, so I added yours: http://jsperf.com/plus-vs-number/2 As is often the case, slower on some, faster on others (which surprised me).

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: If it's end-user input, using `parseInt` with a radix is usually the best way to go.

Comment: ok you means because `+` doesn't raise an exception on wrong input but parseInt does I just read [The Error object and throwing your own errors](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/trycatch2.shtml)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: `parseInt` doesn't raise exceptions. No, I mean because users do things like input `010` and such, and they mean 10, not 8, but some engines will treat `010` as octal. Hence giving the radix.

Comment: Oh I see that the reason..., yes I check `parseInt("string_not_a_number")` gives NaN. In the page I linked checks NaN using  `isNaN()`. Got it now many many thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Simple use `+value`, Notice `+` in front of a variable with converts the variable to a number

```
switch (+value) {
    case 9:
        return 12;
    case 12:
        return 9;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.  `parseInt()` function does parse a string and returns an integer.

```
var value =  parseInt(event.currentTarget.value, 10);
```